# Sending variables from one nodes to another

Tags: ros, python, ros-hydro, environment-variables

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all !
I am using Hydro version of ROS. I have created a node in which I made a variable and store the value in it. Now I have to pass that variable value to another node. So that it can access it.
Can any body tell me how I can do the above thing. I am working on python so it would be nice if anybody tells me in python
Thanks
Looking forward for answers !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173888/sending-variables-from-one-nodes-to-another/) by [jashanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/14866/jashanvir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2014-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many ways how to pass data from one node to another.

You could publish your variable in a topic: [Tutorial Understanding Topics](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics)

You could use a Setter like service: [Tutorial Understanding Services](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams)

And some more advanced ways to do it.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2